# jQuery collapse ul after h-elements except current

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For this website I'm having a menu like, generated by markdown via [MIIS](https://miis.azurewebsites.net/)

```
<h4><a>title</a></h4>
<ul>
  <li><a>foo</a></li>
  <li> <a>foo</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>sub</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 <li><a>foo</a></li>
</ul>

<h4><a>other title</a></h4>

<ul>
  <li><a>other…</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

By default I only want to show the h4 titles, not the lists below it. Only when you click a title, it show show the ul content (only showing the first level below). clicking on another title should hide the other ul content of other section and show current ul below the title.

I'm currently stuck with the collapsing code in common.js, everything is always collapsed:

```
$('.miis-toc > ul > li > a').filter(function(){
        return ($(this).attr('href') != '');
    }).parent().find('ul > li').hide();

    $('.miis-toc > h4').filter(function(){
          return ($(this).attr('href') != '');
     }).parent().find('ul').hide();


currLink.parentsUntil('.miis-toc > ul').last().find('li').show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and understand the way your menu HTML is defined and structured, then a possible solution might be to revise your jQuery like so:

```
// Hide all ul sublists that are direct children of .miis-toc by
// default
$('> ul', '.miis-toc').hide()

// Listen for click event on h4 elements that are directly under
// .miis-toc
$('> h4', '.miis-toc').click(function() {
  
  // Hide all ul sublists that are direct children of .miis-toc
  $('> ul', '.miis-toc').hide()
  
  // Show the ul sublist that is "after" the h4 that has been clicked
  // (ie this)
  $('+ ul', this).show()
  
  // Prevent default click behaviour
  return false; 
})
```

Please see a [completed example of this solution on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3ys0arv/11/)

#### Updated answer

For the new details that were clarified in the comments below, the following solution should meet all requirements. Note that the JS code will "pre-toggle" menu UL or sub-UL based on URL matching (ie based on the browsers URL pathname).

You will need to update you HTML as follows:

```
<div class="miis-toc">
  <h4><a href="/title/">title</a></h4>
  <!-- If path name is /title/, entire tree to this point will be 
       preopened to here -->
  <ul>
    <li><a>foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="/foo/">foo</a> 
      <!-- If path name is /foo/, entire tree to this point will 
           be preopened to here -->
      <ul>
        <li><a>sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a>foo</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h4><a>other title</a></h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a>other…</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

And your updated jQuery as follows:

```
// This code block sets up the menu when the page first loads, and
// decides which UL or UL sublist to display based on current URL
{
    // Hide all UL's that are under .miis-toc
  $('ul', '.miis-toc').hide()
  
  // Look for a UL sublist after an anchor with href matching our 
  // browsers current pathname
  var node = $('a[href="'+location.pathname+'"] + ul', '.miis-toc')

  // If not found, look for a UL after an h4 with child anchors href
  // matching our browsers current pathname
  if(node.length === 0) {
    var a = $('h4 a[href="'+location.pathname+'"]', '.miis-toc')
    node = $('+ ul', a.parent())
  }

  // If we have found a UL or UL sublist, we need to walk back up the 
  // "menu tree" and "show" each node (ie UL and/or UL sublist)
  if(node.length) {
    var parent = node 
    // When we reach to top of the menu (ie .miis-toc), terminate the
    // loop
    while(!parent.hasClass('miis-toc')) {
      parent.show()
      parent = parent.parent() 
    }
  }
}

// Listen for click event on h4 and nested li > a elements under
// .miis-toc
$('h4, li > a', '.miis-toc').click(function(event) {
  
  // Toggle (show/hide) adjacent ul sublist when clicked
  $('+ ul', this).toggle()
  
  // Prevent default click behaviour
  return false; 
})
```

Comment: this collapses the items by default, which is good and shows the lists when clicking but when selecting an item of the list that particular list (or subtree-section) should stay open. The code with "currLink.parentsUntil('.miis-toc > ul').last().find('li').show()" seems to conflict now, which handels the current active (sub)tree-section does not work anymore now.

Comment: Ok - your question seems to say that clicking the titles (ie h4) is what triggers the showing and hiding of lists. 
Firstly - the javascript code in my answer is not intended to work alongside your existing code, but should replace your existing javascript code.
Second - are you wanting to support open and close of sub-trees also? If so, how are they triggered?

Comment: well actually I want to have all ul's closed at first. when clicking an h4 element it should show list below it (first level only). When clicking an ul > li and if it contains a sublist (ul > li > ul) it should expand again the first level only.
 when navigating a page, the h4 + (sub)lists  to the current page/list item should be open. The behavior should show only the current active (sub)tree and collapse others when not needed. Hope this is more detailed info?

Comment: thanks, got it working a bit differently but by using 85% of your suggestions! great!

Comment: Fantastic, glad I could help you :-)